# How to install correctly WSO2 API manager?

Tags: java, wso2

I was trying to install ws02 API manger and this error appeared but I do not know how to fix it or what that means, can someone tell me what I did wrong. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: What changes did you do before starting the server? did you change DB or change any configurations?

Comment: Chashikajw I did nothing just downloaded the .deb file  and install it then I tried to run the .sh file that was all.

Comment: Okay to get things more clear can you restart the machine and run it again.

Comment: I already did it

Comment: Please add the error as text to your question (instead of as an image). See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Okay, maybe your installation hasn't been done correctly. First, uninstall and remove your wso2am folder. After that as the simplest installation, you can download the wso2am product zip file from this. https://wso2.com/api-management/.   Use zip archive option or any other option like APT. If you download zip archive you can extract it and go to bin folder and run it

Comment: @chashikajw I have fixed by restaring my machine, I had the JDK but not the JRE so I installed it and restared my machine then everything went okay, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

When starting API Manager, it will add an admin user to the configured data store. As per the error logs, there is already an admin user which exists in the data store. Thus, Remove that admin user and restart the server. If you want that previously created admin user together with this new admin user then perform the below-mentioned configurations in `APIM_HOME/repository/conf/deployment.toml`. Here you are changing the default admin username to a new username as `admin` is already existing in the DB.

```
[super_admin]
username = "admin_new"
password = "admin_new"
create_admin_account = true
```